# Problems doing an S3 CopyObject using AWS PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3

I'm developing an API which let's my webapp manipulate some files in memory and also using AWS S3 via the AWS SDK for PHP.

Basically my webapp does a curl request to a PHP file on my API box and that works fine for GetObject and PutObject but a CopyObject results in:

1. My browser hanging until it eventually times out
2. The file being copied successfully
3. The copy operation being repeated.  In other words if I delete the destination file in AWS S3, it gets overwritten again and again until I restart the apache2 service on my API webserver.

The receiving PHP file (on the API webserver) outputs a simple resultcode (0 or 1) to indicate whether the requested operation was successful or not.

The offending line is below:

```
$s3->copyObject(array('Bucket' => $strDestinationPath,'Key'    => $in_destination_filename,'CopySource' => $strSourcePath."/".$in_source_filename));
```

My code tests 4 scenarios via curl from my web server to my api server.  My apache logs on the API box show 3 http200 (ok) responses, not the fourth, even though it achieves the filecopy.  I've also quadruple checked I'm using valid bucket names and AWS S3 permissions.

Any suggestions would be gratefully received.